# getting RuntimeError when running with taipy

Tags: taipy

I try to work with taipy but i am getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: The Werkzeug web server is not designed to run in production. Pass allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True to the run() method to disable this error.
```

I am working with docker-compose, this is my **docker-compose.yml**:
version: "3.9"
services:

```
   my_test:
        build: .
        container_name: my_test
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
```

This in my **Dockerfile**:
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]

This is my **requirements.txt**:

```
docker
gpt-engineer
flask==2.2
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.26.1
taipy
```

and this is my **app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from taipy import Gui

flask_app = Flask(__name__)

@flask_app.route("/home")
def home_page():
    return "The home page."

gui = Gui(page="# Taipy application", flask=flask_app)
gui.run(allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True)
```

and i am getting this **output**:

```
ilai@ilai-dell-g15-5520:~/Code/taipy$ docker compose up
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Network taipy_default  Created                                                                                                                  0.1s
 ⠿ Container my_test      Created                                                                                                                  0.1s
Attaching to my_test
my_test  |  * Server starting on http://127.0.0.1:5000
my_test  | Traceback (most recent call last):
my_test  |   File "/app/./app.py", line 11, in <module>
my_test  |     gui.run(allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True)
my_test  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/taipy/gui/gui.py", line 1151, in run
my_test  |     return self._server.runWithWS(
my_test  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/taipy/gui/server.py", line 253, in runWithWS
my_test  |     self._ws.run(self._flask, host=host, port=port, debug=debug, use_reloader=use_reloader)
my_test  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 641, in run
my_test  |     raise RuntimeError('The Werkzeug web server is not '
my_test  | RuntimeError: The Werkzeug web server is not designed to run in production. Pass allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True to the run() method to disable this error.
```

I tried to work without flask and got the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is having `flask==2.2` a requirement? Taipy already installs Flask as one of its requirements and this other version solves your issue.

These requirements normally let you deploy your application:

```
taipy
docker
gpt-engineer
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.26.1
```

Comment: Thanks, after removing the flask i got this error:

Comment: File "/app/./app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from taipy import Gui
...
    from .app import create_app as _create_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/taipy/rest/app.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import api
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/taipy/rest/api/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/taipy/rest/api/views.py", line 155, in <module>
    @blueprint.before_app_first_request
AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'before_app_first_request'

Comment: I would suggest having it in the same order if you have not done it. I am also testing why it brings these errors on my side